# How to ignore lines from tbl2 while main table is tbl1 in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
Visit
tmstamp,   trackno, qno, service
01/01/2011,1,       01,  Sv1
01/01/2011,2,       03,  Sv1
01/01/2011,3,       04,  Sv2
01/01/2011,4,       06,  Sv2
01/02/2011,1,       01,  Sv1

Matter
tmstamp,   trackno, code
01/01/2011,1,       a
01/01/2011,1,       b
01/01/2011,1,       e
01/01/2011,2,       c
01/01/2011,2,       b
01/01/2011,3,       c
01/01/2011,3,       a
01/01/2011,4,       d
01/01/2011,4,       c
01/02/2011,1,       a
01/02/2011,1,       b

select service, count(qno) as 'qno_served' from visit group by service

service, qno_served
SV1,     3
SV2,     2
```

My current statement is how many `qno` they have for each `service`.

I want to twist my statement so that I will link to `matter` table. And check that whether each `qno` has a `code` "a".

If a `qno` has a `code` "a", I don't want to count in.

So, my final result will b linke this.

```
service, qno_served
SV1,     1
SV2,     1
```

Shall I use join or wht method to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Service, COUNT(qno) AS [qno_served]
  FROM Visit
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Matter WHERE Matter.TrackNo = Visit.TrackNo AND Matter.code = 'a')
 GROUP BY Service
```

Comment: This looks like it would execute the query in the WHERE clause for each row in the Visit table which wouldn't be efficient.

Comment: @tponthieux See http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Comment: As the link @Martin posted points out, that's really not necessarily true. This is a very common construction for anti semi joins and SQL Server is adept at handling it. It can use hash and merge join iterators (not just nested loop), neither of which require iterating over the inner table more than once. The same holds true of other correlated subqueries, such as semi joins (EXISTS in the where clause) or correlated subqueries in the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 V.service
,COUNT(1) AS qno_served

FROM MyDatabase.dbo.Visit AS V

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    M.trackno

    FROM MyDatabase.dbo.Matter AS M

    WHERE M.code = 'a'
) AS T
    ON V.trackno = T.trackno

WHERE T.Trackno IS NULL

GROUP BY V.service

ORDER BY service
```